# how to edit or export stored procedures in phpmyadmin on cpanel?

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I am unable to export or edit stored procedures from c panel in phpmyadmin plugin. I searched a lot on the internet but did not got the expected result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

In phpmyadmin Export tab, just scroll down at place "Object creation options" there are options to select function and procedure with exporting database.

Comment: that option only returns drop statement of procedure not the implementation of procedure , BTW thanks for your comment.

Comment: you need to select both options

1. Add DROP TABLE / VIEW / PROCEDURE / FUNCTION / EVENT / TRIGGER statement
2. Add CREATE PROCEDURE / FUNCTION / EVENT statement